# C# Regex - match a substring in a filename

Tags: c#, regex

My regex is really poor so I need help with a c# regex expression that can match a substring after the last backslash.

Typical input:

```
D:\DataFiles\Files_81\aars2016FAKH1800010.pdf
```

I need to check if the filename aars2016FAKH1A800010.pdf contains "FAKH1". It is important that only the filename is evaluated.

It must be done with C# regex, so please no "Contains"

You might be wondering why regex, but this is going to be used in a generic c# application that can evaluate regex expressions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This _shouldn't_ be done with Regex, it should be done with `FileInfo` or the `Path` static methods.  The framework already has support for this, you do not need the overhead and maintainability costs that come with Regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `\\\w*(FAKH)\w*\.pdf` pattern.

```
bool isExsit = Regex.IsMatch(@"D:\DataFiles\Files_81\aars2016FAKH1800010.pdf", @"\\\w*(FAKH)\w*\.pdf");
```

**EDIT**

You can use `Groups[1].Value` get `FAKH`

```
var result = Regex.Match(@"D:\DataFiles\Files_81\aars2016FAKH1800010.pdf", @"\\\w*(FAKH)\w*\.pdf");
var FAKH = result.Groups[1].Value;
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Y7uaj)

Comment: But is it possible to just return the word it self not the entire filename. \\\w*(FAKH)\w*\.pdf returns aars2016FAKH1800010.pdf. I would like to just return FAKH

Comment: @PeterForsbom edit my answer

Comment: But I do not have access to the C# code. I have an application written in C#. This application evaluates file paths. In this application I can enter regex expressions.

Comment: I can just enter: (FAKH) but that will also get hits on the file path. I need to just evaluate everything after the last "\"

Comment: @PeterForsbom You need to use regex group in c# otherwise you can't get `FAKH`. How about use the  `\\\w*(FAKH)\w*\`.pdf` if that return value we can know the result is `FAKH`